# SQL Server 2016 SP1 : date function bug - has anyone faced this issue before?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Something weird happened when I executed the same query in SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2016 SP1. The output was totally different, in fact I am getting wrong output in SQL Server 2016 SP1.

Here is the code which generates minute wise datetime for entire month.

Does anyone know why this happens?

```
    -- number of calls with predefined start time, end time and interval
    DECLARE @start_time DATETIME;   -- starting from here
    DECLARE @end_time DATETIME;     -- until the time is under this value
    DECLARE @interval CHAR(3);      -- interval definition (e.g. day, minute etc.)
    DECLARE @increment INT;         -- interval increment 
    DECLARE @loop_time DATETIME;    -- variable used in the loop
    DECLARE @times TABLE(start_time DATETIME);
        
    SET @start_time = '2020-10-01 00:00:00';
    SET @end_time = '2020-10-31 23:59:59';
    SET @interval = 'mi';
    SET @increment = 1;
        
    SET @loop_time = @start_time;
        
    WHILE @loop_time < @end_time 
    BEGIN 
        IF @interval = 'yy' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(yy, @increment, @loop_time);   -- year
        IF @interval = 'qq' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(qq, @increment, @loop_time);   -- quarter
        IF @interval = 'mm' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(mm, @increment, @loop_time);   -- month
        IF @interval = 'dy' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(dy, @increment, @loop_time);   -- day of year
        IF @interval = 'dd' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(dd, @increment, @loop_time);   -- day
        IF @interval = 'wk' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(wk, @increment, @loop_time);   -- week
        IF @interval = 'dw' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(dw, @increment, @loop_time);   -- weekday
        IF @interval = 'hh' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(hh, @increment, @loop_time);   -- hour
        IF @interval = 'mi' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(mi, @increment, @loop_time);   -- minute
        IF @interval = 'ss' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(ss, @increment, @loop_time);   -- second
        IF @interval = 'ms' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(ms, @increment, @loop_time);   -- millisecond
        IF @interval = 'mcs' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(mcs, @increment, @loop_time); -- microsecond
        IF @interval = 'ns' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(ns, @increment, @loop_time);   -- nanosecond
        INSERT INTO @times(start_time) VALUES (@loop_time);
        --SET @loop_time = @loop_time;
    END;

    SELECT * FROM @times
```

Comment: Are you going to add your 2012 and 2016 outputs, or did you intend for your question to only be testable by people who happen to have both handy?

Comment: OK, but does it address my question? Please also define "wrong" in "wrong output"... Add your 2012 output, add your 2016 output, point out why they differ, and why 2016 is "wrong"

Comment: Oh.. youre in luck.. Turns out I do have a 2012 kicking around and dbfiddle's 2016 is working... Couldn't find anything different or what I'd class as "wrong", but I'll admit I haven't checked all 45000 rows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZa0s.png

Comment: I have got no idea what you're talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIWlT.png

Comment: Expected Output (which i am getting in 2012)

'2020-10-01 00:00:00.000'
'2020-10-01 00:01:00.000'
'2020-10-01 00:02:00.000'
.
.
.
'2020-11-01 00:00:00.000'

Output in 2016 SP1

'2020-10-01 00:00:00.000'
'2020-10-01 00:01:00.000'
'2020-10-01 00:02:00.000'
.
.
.
'2020-10-28 16:24:00.000'

Comment: Put an orderby on and check again. See my posted screenshots; I promise you both resultsets have 44,640 rows and start and end with the same times (per screenshots). Always expect rows to emit in a random order unless there is an orderby

Comment: What a silly mistake i should have checked it before. Thanks @Caius Jard.

Comment: Hah, no worries.. Sometimes we just look and look at something and can't see it "hiding in plain sight" :)

Comment: Can I ask you to consider marking an answer to this? Click the grey check mark next to the answer you ultimately used so that the question shows as answered on the dashboard..

Answer (score 1):

If interested, there is another approach rather than LOOPING

**Example**

```
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Range]('2020-10-01','2020-10-31 23:59:59','MI',1)
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
2       2020-10-01 00:01:00.000
3       2020-10-01 00:02:00.000
4       2020-10-01 00:03:00.000
5       2020-10-01 00:04:00.000
6       2020-10-01 00:05:00.000
...
44639   2020-10-31 23:58:00.000
44640   2020-10-31 23:59:00.000
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Date-Range] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr 
                                           When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr 
                                           When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr 
                                           When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr 
                                           When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr 
                                           When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr 
                                           When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr 
                                           When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr 
                                           End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Range]('2020-10-01','2020-10-31 23:59:59','MI',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Range]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2012 generates the datetime till '1 Nov 2020 00:00:00'

Indeed, and why wouldn't it:

```
WHILE @loop_time < @end_time 
    BEGIN 
        ...
        IF @interval = 'mi' SET @loop_time = DATEADD(mi, @increment, @loop_time);   -- minute
```

- So `@loop_time = 23:58:00`..
- You add a minute so it's `23:59:00`,
- You insert `23:59:00`,
- It's less than `23:59:59`,
- You add a minute so it's 24:00:00 (or 00:00:00 the next day in other words),
- You insert `00:00:00`,
- You test it, it's no longer less than 23:59:59
- Loop stops; last insert made was `00:00:00`